# Sencha Touch 2.1.x newbie questions - trying to follow an online guide

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Just downloaded the sencha complete trial as I want to try my hand at mobile apps.  I am trying to follow the guide located at http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/ just go get an idea of how everything goes.  Right off the bat I am having a problem.

The guide at 'Organizing A Sencha Touch Application In Directories And Files' shows the file structure.  Well, I open Sencha Architect and choose to create a new Sencha Touch 2.1.x project.  Project Inspector shows nothing similar to what the guide does.  Is this guide for an older version or what?  I am assuming this is my directory structure, but completely different than what is listed.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

The file structure in that guide does appear to be correct, but of course, I would always trust the product from the creator of the framework over an external guide. Thing is, ST2 let's you put things lots of different places and customize those locations in `app.js` and `app.json`. I wouldn't worry about the folder structure if you're going through Architect so much as it will put things where they need to go and it'll include them in your `app.js` file correctly.

That all said, you may want to check the official [Sencha documentation on Architect](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide) for any questions like this.